# Validating integer part of an string

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I have a text file that I need to convert each line into integer.

The lines can begin with '#' to indicate a comment. Also, after the data it might be inline comment too...again indicated by '#'

So I have the example below:

```
QString time = "5000 #this is 5 seconds";  // OK      
QString time = "  5000 # this is 5 seconds"; // OK..free spaceis allowed at start        
QString time = "5000.00 #this is 5 seconds"; // invalid...no decimal 
QString time = "s5000 # this is 5 seconds"; // invalid...does not start with numerical character
```

How can I take care of these cases? I mean in all the 4 example above except the last two I need to extract "5000". How to find out the last one is invalid?

So I mean what is the best fail-proof code to handle this task?

Comment: Your comment in codes says last two are invalid, where as in post you say only last one is invalid? Whats the correct statement?

Comment: 1: regular expression, 2: boost.spirit parser, 3: other parser.

Comment: The regex you want to use is `[0-9]\+`. If it matches, use `QString::toInt`.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi corrected now

Comment: You could perhaps use `QTime` instead of `QString` and then you'd get your compiler to verify it for you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo My case is about duration rather than actual time

Comment: @Dekker: `QTime time = QTime(0, 0, 5);` // 5 seconds

Comment: The question's a little confusing because there are two numbers in each sample string, but it seems like you only want to validate that the first one is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another example using `std::regex`. Converting `QString` to a `string_view` is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::string> extract_number(std::string_view input)
{
    static constexpr char expression[] = R"xx(^\s*(\d+)\s*(#.*)?$)xx";
    static const auto re = std::regex(expression);

    auto result = std::optional<std::string>();
    auto match = std::cmatch();
    const auto matched = std::regex_match(input.begin(), input.end(), match, re);
    if (matched)
    {
        result.emplace(match[1].first, match[1].second);
    }

    return result;
}

void emit(std::string_view candidate, std::optional<std::string> result)
{
    std::cout << "offered: " << candidate << " - result : " << result.value_or("no match") << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    const std::string_view candidates[] = 
    {
"5000 #this is 5 seconds",
"  5000 # this is 5 seconds",
"5000.00 #this is 5 seconds",
"s5000 # this is 5 seconds"
    };

    for(auto candidate : candidates)
    {
        emit(candidate, extract_number(candidate));
    }
}
```

expected output:

```
offered: 5000 #this is 5 seconds - result : 5000
offered:   5000 # this is 5 seconds - result : 5000
offered: 5000.00 #this is 5 seconds - result : no match
offered: s5000 # this is 5 seconds - result : no match
```

https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b0e088e6ed0576b

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to validate and extract the digit from first grouping pattern that will capture your number,

```
^\s*(\d+)\b(?!\.)
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `\s*` - Allows optional space before the number
- `(\d+)` - Captures the number and places it in first grouping pattern
- `\b` - Ensures the number does not match partially in a larger text because of the negative look ahead present ahead
- `(?!\.)` - Rejects the match if there is a decimal following the number

**[Demo1](https://regex101.com/r/Kpml1P/1)**

In case only last one is invalid, you can use this regex to capture number from first three entries,

```
^\s*(\d+)
```

**[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/Kpml1P/2/)**